# Using the Instagram API to create a profile

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

I am interested in using Instagram to create a Tinder-like app. One would connect via Instagram, create a basic profile, and then choose selected photos from his/her instagram. There should be no limit (I believe some users online have said there is a limit of the latest 33 instagram photos)..I would want users to be able to select any of their Instagram photos (perhaps 9 or 12) and use this for their profile (kind of like what Tinder does but with Facebook).

Answer (score 0):

If you let users login via Instagram then the API will have no limit, you can access all photos and use in your app.